# Python: TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python

When I was trying to run this:

```
lista=[4,10,4,15,6,15,18,10,7]
listb=[5,10,5,18,11,35,21,10,7]

import math

for i in range(9):
    a=math.log10(lista[i])
    b=math.log10(listb[i])
    lista=lista.insert(i,a)
    listb=listb.insert(i,b)

for i in range(17,8,-1):
    lista.remove(lista[i])
    listb.remove(listb[i])

print(lista)
print(listb)
```

Then I got :

```
File "C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/xy/untitled3.py", line 11, in <module>
   a=math.log10(lista[i])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I need help. Thank you very much

Comment: Please try to explain more about how you have tried to solve the problem yourself, or provide links or other evidence that you have attempted to find a solution. This will help prevent your questions from being downvoted in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `insert()` doesn't return *anything* and so you are assigning `None` to your lists in the following lines:

```
lista=lista.insert(i,a)
listb=listb.insert(i,b)
```

Just doing the following is enough:

```
lista.insert(i,a)
listb.insert(i,b)
```

#### Examples

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a.insert(1,1)

>>> print b
None

>>> print a
[1,1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

`lista.insert()` returns `None` because the list is altered in-place, and does *not* return the updated list.

During the second iteration of the loop then `lista` is `None` and `lista[i]` fails.

Don't assign the result of the insertion:

```
for i in range(9):
    a=math.log10(lista[i])
    b=math.log10(listb[i])
    lista.insert(i,a)
    listb.insert(i,b)
```

With that correction, your code prints:

```
[0.6020599913279624, 0.6020599913279624, 0.6020599913279624, 0.6020599913279624, 0.6020599913279624, 0.6020599913279624, 0.6020599913279624, 0.6020599913279624, 0.6020599913279624]
[0.6989700043360189, 0.6989700043360189, 0.6989700043360189, 0.6989700043360189, 0.6989700043360189, 0.6989700043360189, 0.6989700043360189, 0.6989700043360189, 0.6989700043360189]
```